# Why does code execute even after specifying return - background thread to main thread issue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

- I have a code that hits the server, goes through a list of names & finds me a name that matches my query
- I am handling errors by putting the entire server request on a background thread & deal with errors using throw statements (basically the function throws)
- When I have an error - say for example "failed to connect to server", the throw statement gets called successfully & is caught successfully at the catch block.

Problem is that whenever I have an error, I need to update UI on main thread. I use dispatchQueue.main.async to do this & use a return statement. But the code after the return statement still gets executed. What am I doing wrong?

In the below code, the **catch block** for **enum error case of .queueNetworkFailed** gets called successfully. But looks like **return** **does not stop program execution**. The **code** **after the do - catch statement still gets executed**. Is it because of background to main thread faulty handling?

```
    func startConnection(){
        getServerTimestamp { (timestamp, error) in
            guard let timestampTemp = timestamp?.dateValue().timeIntervalSince1970 else {return}
            let timestamp = Int(timestampTemp)
            self.connectButtonPressedTimestamp = timestamp
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                var partnerUid: String?
                self.buildServerQuery()
                
                do {
                    partnerUid = try self.findConnection()
                } catch let error {
                    switch error as? ConnectError{
                    case .queueNetworkFail: //CALLED SUCCESSFULLY
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.userState = 1
                            return //EXPECT FUNCTION TO STOP HERE BUT...
                        }
                    case .queueEmptyAtServer:
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.establishState4()
                            return
                        }
                    case .queueEmptyAtLocal:
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.establishState4()
                            return
                        }
                    case .none:
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.userState = 1
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if let partnerUid = partnerUid{ //FUNCTION EXECUTION CONTINUES DESPITE RETURN
                    self.finalizeConnection(partnerUid: partnerUid)
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Something went wrong")
                        self.userState = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning from the flow of execution within the Dispatched Main Queue. You should return from the outside of the main queue to stop the execution of the following code in present queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.userState = 1
}
return //EXPECT TO STOP HERE...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try it out & mark it as the correct answer

Comment: You're welcome. It should work. You can check it out with a simple example by trying to create a function and return from within dispatch queue and outside the dispatch queue.